# Streamlit file uploader error in VCF file format

Tags: python, streamlit

I want to read vcf file using streamlit file uploader. but i am getting TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not UploadedFile

```
import io.
import os
import pandas as pd
import streamlit as st

ifile=st.file_uploader('choose a file')
if ifile is not None:

  def read_vcf(path):
      with open(ifile, 'r') as f:
          lines = [l for l in f if not l.startswith('##')]
      return pd.read_csv(
          io.StringIO(''.join(lines)),
          dtype={'#CHROM': str, 'POS': int, 'ID': str, 'REF': str, 'ALT': str,
                'QUAL': str, 'FILTER': str, 'INFO': str},
          sep='\t'
      ).rename(columns={'#CHROM': 'CHROM'})
  st.write(read_vcf(ifile))
```

Comment: Could you provide the same file for us so that we can try the code? or just give a sample file URL!

Comment: Have you read this from Streamlit documentation. Look at the end of the page and try to upload your file. I guess it is going to be fine. By the way, they are not using Pandas so I am wondering what is the benefit of using it?
https://docs.streamlit.io/library/api-reference/widgets/st.file_uploader